# Best practice to keep flow of fixed divs below one another when the top goes sticky

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is a more theoretical question as I am looking for the best approach to the following scenario.

[image]

Divs are naturally aligned one after the other (vertically) by CSS, so it is no problem to build the structure on the left image. The top div contains some text and images, whereas the second one contains only tabs. The top div with the information goes sticky when the page is scrolled (picture on the right). I don't hide all the information inside, meaning not all of its children will be hidden.

I set both divs with a fixed position and gave them identical z-index. This placed them on top of the page when scrolling. To reduce the content of the top div, I set display: none to the elements which I don't want to see when the page is scrolled. Neither visibility nor opacity removes the space occupied by the "released" elements. To keep the second div (with the tabs) aligned below the sticky header, I used jQuery and set dynamically its top attribute depending on whether the page is scrolled or not.

Problems arise when I try to animate the transition from normal to sticky. My question is what method should I use to animate the sticky one and to make the following div flow naturally and take its place below the sticky one when the scrollbar is active. Can the two be aligned without jQuery? How can I animate the changing height of the top one when I don't know its actual height?

**EDIT**

I managed to build a similar behaviour in JSFiddle. You could see how inappropriate the tabs' animation is and how the animation doesn't work for the header section above. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozky57h7/11/)

*jQuery code:*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".tabs").css("top", function() {
    return $(".header").outerHeight(true);
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $(".description").css("display", "none");
      $(".about").css("display", "none");
    }
    else {
      $(".description").css("display", "block");
      $(".about").css("display", "block");
    }

    $(".tabs").css("top", Math.max($(".header").outerHeight(true), 0 - $(this).scrollTop()));
  });
});
```

*CSS:*

```
.header {
   background-color: grey;
   color: white;
   position: fixed;
   transition: height 0.2s linear;
   -moz-transition: height 0.2s linear; /* FF 4 */
   -webkit-transition: height 0.2s linear; /* Safari & Chrome */
   -o-transition: height 0.2s linear; /* Opera */
 }

 .centered {
    text-align: center;
 }

 .tabs {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    transition: top 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: top 0.2s linear; /* FF 4 */
    -webkit-transition: top 0.2s linear; /* Safari & Chrome */
    -o-transition: top 0.2s linear; /* Opera */
 }

 #tabList li {
     display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: you may show us your current code or a working example (dummy). For stickyness I can recommend: [waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/). When you hide elements completly (display) you cannot animate them so I recommend setting a fix height value for the header. You can animate the height of the header while hiding the other elements (e.g. opacity) for a nice fade effect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've added a demo scenario above. I would like not to set heights manually as the header will vary in size. Regarding opacity, I could give it a try but then what about the space they would still occupy?